# How to swap columns in such a file?

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a text file, each line is stored like this :

```
"Video or movie"    "parent"    "Media or entertainment"    "1" "1" "1" "0" "0"
```

I want to swap the columns 3 with 2, i.e.

```
"Video or movie"   "Media or entertainment"  "parent"   "1" "1" "1" "0" "0"
```

How to do it in linux in a shell script or any other scripting language? I just need a simplest and quickest way of doing it.

Comment: Your last sentence is incomplete.

Comment: You could give R a try.

Comment: A CSV processor, with whitespace as the column separator?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Can you gives us an example here how you would do it with R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It can be done with `awk` using `"` as the field separator. But doing that, you must remember that `$1` is empty, `$2` holds the first string, `$3` is the space between strings, `$4` is the second string, etc. Also, it's more reliable to swap the two strings instead of just printing all the fields and hoping you put enough `$n`s. Bearing these in mind, the following should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\""} {tmp=$4;$4=$6;$6=tmp;print}' input_file >output_file
```

Comment: +1 for such an elegant use of `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes a quick and dirty `sed` that does it:

```
sed -e 's/^\("[^"]*"\) *\("[^"]*"\) *\("[^"]*"\)/\1 \3 \2/'
```

But will fail for fields with double quotes in their values, etc.

An example:

```
echo \"a\" \"b\" \"c d d d\" \"e\" | sed -e 's/^\("[^"]*"\) *\("[^"]*"\)  *\("[^"]*"\)/\1 \3 \2/'
```

But I'm pretty sure someone will be able to show you an `awk` one-liner that is simpler and better.

Comment: it did not work for this line: "bored of the main" "melody" "main plot" "1" "1" "1" "0" "1.0" "0" "0"

Comment: @frankmoss I get '"bored of the main" "main plot" "melody" "1"', is that not what you want? What are you getting?

Comment: It might be a white-space issue, try changing ` *` to `[ \t]*`.

Comment: @Kevin i get the original line. I replaced with [ \t]* but no change in the result. How does your sed look?

Comment: @frankmoss I put in `echo '"bored of the main" "melody" "main plot" "1"' | sed -e 's/^\("[^"]*"\) *\("[^"]*"\) *\("[^"]*"\)/\1 \3 \2/'`, and got out `"bored of the main" "main plot" "melody" "1"` - copied and pasted, no typos in either. GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: @Kevin if you put the echo stuff in a file, it will not work, check it out...

Comment: @frankmoss Still works from a file. Maybe you somehow got a non-printing character somewhere.

Comment: It works fine for me for both piped and reading from a file via command line arg to sed... The only issue is that currenltly it changes the original width of the first two space-gaps (when they are originally longer than a single space), but that is easily fixable by using a couple more `\(..\) expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with:

```
sed 's/"\(.*\)"/\1/' |
    awk 'BEGIN{FS="\" +\"";OFS="\" \""}{t=$3;$3=$2;$2=t;print}' |
    sed 's/.*/"&"/'
```

The two `sed` scripts handle the leading and trailing double quotes (since they are not delimitors and interfere).  The `BEGIN` clause handles the separation of fields.  The `t=$3;$3=$2;$2=t` is a standard swap fields idiom, then the whole field is printed (with OFS as the field separator).

Comment: it does not work. I send a single line file, and it prints the same file.

Comment: Using your input (`"Video or movie"    "parent"    "Media or entertainment"    "1" "1" "1" "0" "0"`) and copying the above (not using my previous incarnations), I get `"Video or movie" "Media or entertainment" "parent" "1" "1" "1" "0" "0"`.

Answer (score 1):

This method is effectively identical to *Kevin's* `awk` method..  I've include it here just as a comparison between *bash* and *awk*.

```
IFS=\";   # IFS sets up the split-at array delimiter
cat file |
while IFS= read -r line ;do              # Disable IFS for each `read' 
    A=($line)                            # split into array elements
    t="${A[5]}";A[5]="${A[3]}";A[3]="$t" # swap "columns" 2 and 3
    for ((i=1;i<$((${#A[@]}));i++)) ;do
       printf '"%s' "${A[$i]}"           # print each element with a lead "
    done; echo '"'                       # add the final "
done
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
awk '{print $1, $3, $2, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8}' file > newfile
```

Comment: @ramonovsky awk doesn't like combination of quotes and space... i.e. it does not work

Comment: You can specify ' ' as -F (field separator)

Comment: And what does `-F' ' do? The problem is that this will print (e.g. in the first case) `"Video movie" or "parent" ...`, quite clearly not what frank wants.

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions.

**ANSWER ONE: Use `sed` 3 times to do the following:**

1. start with the original line: 12345678
2. duplicate the first two parameters: 1212345678
3. chop the 4th parameter: 121345678
4. chop the 1st parameter: 21345678

Here's the resultant command using `sed` (Using XXX and YYY as helpers to find and remove the 1st and 4th parameters):

```
sed 's/["][^"]*["][^"]*["][^"]*["]/XXX& & YYY/' data.txt | sed 's/["][^"]*["] YYY//' | sed 's/XXX["][^"]*["]//'
```

**ANSWER TWO: Convert data into a script and run it!**

- convert the data.txt into a data.sh by inserting a command (say flipcol.sh)
- run the data.sh

Implement flipcol.sh as:

```
echo '"'$2'"' '"'$1'"' '"'$3'"' '"'$4'"' '"'$5'"' '"'$6'"' '"'$7'"' '"'$8'"'
```

Then run the following command on your data.txt creating a shell script:

```
sed 's!^!./flipcol.sh !' < data.txt > data.sh
```

Then run the newly created shell script

```
./data.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions about the lines in the file: they start with a double-quote, and the field and delimiters don't contain double-quotes.
Then this sed-expression will work:

```
sed 's@^\("[^"]*"[^"]*"\)\([^"]*\)\("[^"]*"\)\([^"]*\)@\1\4\3\2@'
```

If this expression is followed by the text-file's name, it will give the desired output, which can be put into a new file by following the text-file's name by the output redirector `>` and the desired new file's name, like:

```
sed 's@^\("[^"]*"[^"]*"\)\([^"]*\)\("[^"]*"\)\([^"]*\)@\1\4\3\2@' textfile > newfile
```