# swapping words with awk around a symbol/text ("to")

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file that for example says:

```
Aa Bb C Y... "TO" Bb
Cc Z J >> sd "TO" Dd
Ee Z H S DFF "TO" Ff
```

But I want it like that:

```
Bb "TO" Aa Bb C Y... 
Dd "TO" Cc Z J >> sd 
Ff "TO" Ee Z H S DFF
```

So I can swap the Texts aroud the "TO"...

Comment: So every time the maker "to" appears, you want to swap the words before and after this marker?

Comment: @Fiximan - the 2nd line appears to be unchanged, otherwise this would be a simple case of swapping two columns (and [that's a duplicate too](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31586)...)

Comment: @don_crissti ... didn't realise the unformatted code and thought we were talking about all entries on a single line. Either way: I would be astonished if such task wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: `awk -F' "TO" ' '{print $2,$1}' OFS=' "TO" ' infile` if you're on a `gnu` setup... and as I said, this has been asked before, several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk -F" \"TO\" " '{print $2 " \"TO\" " $1}' yourfile
```

Comment: note that saying `print $2, "TO", $1` produces the same output and it is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do:

```
awk -F ' "TO" ' '{print $2 FS $1}'
```

`-F` defines the field separator (`FS` variable). That assumes the lines only have one occurrence of `"TO"` and that it's surrounded by spaces.

With `perl`, you could have more control like:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 's/^(.*?)(\h*)("TO")(\h*)(.*)$/$5$4$3$2$1/'
```

to also move the blanks around the `"TO"` around.